# How do I make the height of a horizontal bar chart flexible in order to be resized when new data has been added in?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

If I have a container, in this case my canvas, how I can set the height of a bar to be flexible?
In short, if a new data in dataArray will be added, the height of the bar has to change in order to fit the new data and remain inside my canvas.

I hope that make sense.

This is the code:

```
var dataArray = [3, 20, 34, 50, 50, 50, 50, 60];

var width = 500;
var height = 500;

var widthScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(dataArray)])
                    .range([0, width - 100]);

var color = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([d3.min(dataArray), d3.max(dataArray)])
                .range(["red", "blue"]);

var x_axis = d3.axisBottom()
                .scale(widthScale);

var canvas = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(10,0)")

var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
                .data(dataArray)
                .enter() //
                    .append("rect") //
                    .attr("width", function (d) { return widthScale(d); })
                    .attr("height", 50)
                    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d); })
                    .attr("y", function (d, i) { return (i * 51); });

canvas.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,480)")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(widthScale));
```

Thank you so much for that.

Comment: scaleBand would be best for this - see https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#scaleBand

Comment: You might edit the question to clarify that the chart is a horizontal bar chart. @TomShanley's solution seems appropriate. An example can be seen here with explanations: https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-scaleband

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution.

I had to resize the height of bars based on the dataset and the height of the canvas, minus a padding which I set as variable, in my case 1.

After that, I had to specify on the "y" to return i * the height / length of the dataset.

Here's the code of only the bars:

```
var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
                .data(dataArray)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("width", function (d) { return widthScale(d); }) 
                .attr("height", height / dataArray.length - barPadding) 
                .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d); })
                .attr("y", function (d, i) { return i * (height / dataArray.length) - 20); });
```

and this is the final version of the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>D3</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<script>

var dataArray = [3, 20, 34, 50, 60];

var width = 500;
var height = 500;

var widthScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(dataArray)])
                    .range([0, width - 100]);
var barPadding = 1;


var color = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([d3.min(dataArray), d3.max(dataArray)])
                .range(["red", "blue"]);

var x_axis = d3.axisBottom()
                .scale(widthScale);



var canvas = d3.select("body") 
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width) 
                .attr("height", height)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(10,0)")


var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
                .data(dataArray)
                .enter() 
                    .append("rect") 
                    .attr("width", function (d) { return widthScale(d); })
                    .attr("height", height / dataArray.length - barPadding)
                    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d); })
                    .attr("y", function (d, i) { return i * (height / dataArray.length) - 20); });

canvas.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,480)")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(widthScale));


</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using d3.scaleBand would be as follows. The scaleBand is set up with a padding of 0.1, which means 10% of the height is allocated to padding between the bars and outside of the bars. scaleBand.bandwidth() is a handy tool to give you the height of the bars.

```js
var dataArray = [3, 20, 34, 50, 60];

var width = 500;
var height = 500;
var x_axis_margin = 20

var widthScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(dataArray)])
                    .range([0, width - 100]);
  
var y_scale = d3.scaleBand()
 .domain(dataArray.map((d,i) => i)) // create array of indices
 .range([0, (height - x_axis_margin)])
 .padding(0.1)

var barPadding = 1;

var color = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([d3.min(dataArray), d3.max(dataArray)])
                .range(["red", "blue"]);

var x_axis = d3.axisBottom()
                .scale(widthScale);

var canvas = d3.select("body") 
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width) 
                .attr("height", height)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(10,0)")


var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
                .data(dataArray)
                .enter() 
                    .append("rect") 
                    .attr("width", function (d) { return widthScale(d); })
                    .attr("height", y_scale.bandwidth())
                    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d); })
                    .attr("y", function (d, i) { return y_scale(i); });

canvas.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,"+ (height - x_axis_margin) +")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(widthScale));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```